# Alignment of surfaces to a curve (loop) or vertex...?

Tags: modeling

New to Blender...great program.  Coming from the Rhino nurbs world.

Going through a Blender Guru tutorial on making an anvil.

Have a question...how do you center a series of faces to a centered "loop" or align the faces to a center "vertex"?

Screen shots attached.

Thanks,

M

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks, in this case, as if you should just be able to set your snap to 'Vertex' and 'Active'... select the vertex at the peak last, (so it's the active one) and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> the lot,  hovering over one of the vertices on the central vertical loop to induce the snap.

Either switch on 'Automatically Merge Vertices' in the header before the move, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.. Remove Doubles when you're done.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought...but I can't seem to "snap" to that central loop/vertex.  Faces all selected, vertex points mode on, magnet snap on, vertex mode, target center...nothing.  No snapping.  Even if select that peak vertex and just try to snap that one point to the center...no snapping.

Comment: I wish Blender would call the moving element 'source', and the stationary one 'target'.. or something like that to reduce confusion. Set the target to 'vertex' giving you the option of any of the vertices on the central edge to snap to in Y, and the source to _'active'_ . If the peak vertex is active, this is a vertex-to-vertex snap, in Y only.